# server-side authentication with ssl: sending certificate file from client

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

i've successfully set SSL authentication up with certificates: configured Apache http-client, configured the server (weblogic, CLIENT-CERT login-config if that matters), tested that it works.

however, in the client code i have to hardcode path to trust-store (either manually initializing `TrustManagerFactory` or through respective JVM properties) and its password also and i don't feel it's right. additionally, the certificates have to be manually registered on the client-side with `keytool`, which is also not so flexible.

so, is there a way to completely avoid all that? ideally the client will have certificate file bundled with it, sending it to the server when requested to do so. i tried to google it, but never found how to manually stream a certificate *file*.

**UPDATE**

as suggested [here](http://www.mombu.com/programming/java/t-ssl-for-java-without-keystores-1366416.html), i tried to read certificate file into a new keystore with no password and initialize both `KeyManagerFactory` and `TrustManagerFactory` with this keystore:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
Certificate cer = cf.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("myFile.cer"));

KeyStore defaultKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
defaultKeyStore.load(null, "".toCharArray());
defaultKeyStore.setCertificateEntry("alias", cer);

trustManagerFactory.init(defaultKeyStore);
keyManagerFactory.init(defaultKeyStore, "".toCharArray());

SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

but it didn't work. usual exception "peer not authenticated". i guess it's because i need corresponding private key also, but there's no way to get it...

Comment: You can't get the private key of your own certificate? That doesn't make sense. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trust for example one specific server certificate, you could add the X.509 certificate to your classpath and use an javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager (produced from your TrustManagerFactory). No need for a keystore (and keytool) then.

Comment: it's the other way around: the server has to check client's certificate to decide if it trusts this client.

Comment: In this case you need a keystore containing the clients key and certificate. you could of course bundle it in the JAR and load it from the classpath (Using a KeyManager the same way as the TrustManager) but this wouldn't make sense, since this should be a secret only known to the client.